# futime in python 2.7

Tags: python, unix

Is there a way to call utimes on a file descriptor in python 2.7?  I have the file descriptor but not the filename.  Even if I did have the filename it would be racy.

Google searching shows this is a solved problem in python 3.x.  I'm wondering if the answer is "no" or if I missed something.

Comment: What about converting it with `f = os.fdopen(fd)` (assuming `fd` is the filedescriptor) and getting the filename via `f.name`?

Comment: @ProfHase85 this is still racy (what if the file is replaced between grabbing f.name and writing the utime). On the other it may be the best I could do.

Comment: What about locking it, see here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.lockf

Comment: @ProfHase85 nice idea. such locking is advisory (see http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sektion=2&query=fcntl) , and so would work perfectly for my case but may not be generic enough for security relevant races.  You may want to make your comment an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

What about locking it, see here: [docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.lockf](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.lockf) –  ProfHase85